# JQuery get value from dynamically created input by tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created table with `JQuery` and i would like to get value of `input` elements:

```
$el.append('<tr data-id='+ data[i].id + ' data-token='+data[i].token + '><td>'+data[i].order+'</td>\n\
      <td><input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" value="'+data[i].qty+'" min="1"></td>\n\
   ......
```

With this code i can generate table(this is a fragment of code only).
I know how to access into values of tr tag:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        id = tr.data('id'), // we have the id
        token = tr.data('token'), // we have the token 
        qty = tr.data('qty'); <------------- this not working
 })
```

How to get value of `qty`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Problem:** You don't have a `data-qty` attribute in your `tr`. Also there is no `data-qty` at all in your table.

**Solution:** During your table creation you are assigning the `data[i].qty` to your `input` element as value. Hence you need to read the `input` value. Like below.

```
   qty = tr.find('#qty').val();
```

**NOTE:** Satpal provided a valid point. If at all you are building the `tr` in a loop then you are assigning the same `id` to all the `input` elements in the all the rows which is not recommended. Its better you remove the `id` attribute and just use the `name` attribute to select the element. like

`tr.find('input[name="qty"]').val();` or `tr.find('td:eq(1) input').val()`

However if this is the case then Satpal gave the right answer.

Comment: OP is creating elements dynamically with `id="qty"` it will create invalid HTML. So why not simple `$('#qty').val()` since Id must be unique

Comment: @Satpal we are not sure if he is inside a loop.. If so then you are right.. if not ?? :)

Comment: Then `$('#qty').val()` suffice

Comment: @Satpal you are right.. I have added the details in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

First the `id` should be unique in the same document so you could replace the `id` by class in :

```
<input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" value="'+data[i].qty+'" min="1">
```

Then if you want to get the `input` value you could use `find` and the `class` of the input then `.val()`, so it should be :

```
qty = tr.find('.qty').val();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is creating elements dynamically with `id="qty"` it will create invalid HTML. So why not simple `$('#qty').val()` since Id must be unique

Comment: Thanks fo your intervention but `$('#qty').val()` will not resolve the problem of duplicate `id`'s... i suggest to use the classes instead, check my update.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.find()` in conjunction with [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
qty = tr.find('[name=qty]').val();
```

As you are creating element dynamically with `id="qty"` it will create invalid HTML. Since identifiers must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Since the id of the element is unique, $('#qty').val() is enough.

```
qty = $('#qty').val();
```

Comment: This is not a solution for dynamic generated html elements.

Answer (score 0):

qty = tr.data('qty');
this means you want to access the data attribute, since you are not having any data attribute like "data-qty", you can't access it. So either make it a class or id.